# All repeated integrals on $(-1,1)$ vanishing for a non-zero function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to find a non-zero function $f(x)$ on $(-1,1)$ such that all its repeated integrals vanish?

By repeated integrals I mean sequence of numbers $$ I_n =f^{(-n)}(1)-f^{(-n)}(-1) $$ with

$$ \frac{d}{dx}f^{(-n-1)} = f^{(-n)} \text{ and } f^{(-n-1)}(-1)=0.$$

I have suspition such function might exist, something *similar* to $$\mathrm{sin}(\frac{x}{x^2-1})$$ but I am unable to find an actual example with proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $f$ is necessarily zero (almost everywhere). We have
$$I_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x)^{n-1}f(x)\,dx$$
(easily proven using integration by parts), thus if these are all zeros then
$$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)p(x)\,dx=0$$
for any polynomial $p(x)$, and we proceed by the density of polynomials.

Comment: If you show me or point me to an existing result saying that polynomials are dense in the space of *all* (continuos?) integrable functions on an *open* set $(-1,1)$ then you will convince me.

Comment: Say, if we're looking for $f\in L^2(-1,1)$ (open or closed - doesn't matter, of course), [Weierstrass](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) tells that polynomials are dense in $C[-1,1]$ (w.r.t. its norm, hence w.r.t. the $L^2$ norm) which in turn is dense in $L^2$.

Comment: (The same works for $L^1$, with polynomials approximating [$\operatorname{sgn}f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).)